# What does it mean for a substance to be "sparingly soluble"?

Tags: aqueous-solution, analytical-chemistry, solubility, solutions

I have trouble understanding what solubility means. Merriam-Webster defines it as follows:
1  the quality or state of being soluble
2 the amount of a substance that will dissolve in a given amount of another substance

For this discussion, the "other substance" of #2 will be water. I know that solubility can be represented in g/L (which can be converted in mol/L). Furthermore, when the concentrantion of a solute is equal to its solubility, the solution is said to be "saturated". Now, my first question is what it means for a substance to be sparingly soluble? From what I understand, the will always be a certain quantity of a solute, however small, such that when I put it in water it will be dissolved.

Comment: Such wording as a quantifier isn't very good. It's fuzzy and a bit open to interpretation. It is also a bit ambiguous. So I guess if you want to have a ballpark to play in: the highest concentration is somewhere around 0.1 mol/L or lower, but not as low as like nmol/L or so. But I guess different disciplines do different categories.

Comment: Highly dependent on the specific field. Few dopants in silicon are soluble much above 1 part per million (5E16/cc), and many non-dopants are soluble at even lower levels.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/167106/why-do-we-call-salts-such-as-agcl-sparingly-soluble

Comment: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/14694/when-was-the-term-sparingly-soluble-first-introduced-in-chemistry

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/70247/what-is-meant-by-fairly-when-used-as-a-quantifier-for-the-solubility-of-a-chem

Comment: Instant coffee is soluble in water and Ground coffee is sparingly soluble in water even though both solutions have about the same amount of coffee in them. The term seems to mean if one looks really hard a minute amount of material can be seen to dissolve. Another example is lead chloride PbCl2 A single crystal might just dissolve, definitely will if heated. Calcium and magnesium hydroxides are slightly or sparingly soluble. Pasta or rice are sparingly soluble in water; water is soluble in pasta and rice. It is a matter of degree and observation.